# Saber la aplicacion que esta en primer o segundo plano en Android

Tags: android

Necesito saber la aplicación que esta en primer plano en android, es decir saber la app que esta en un instante dado abierta mostrándose en pantalla digamos.

Comment: Pista, onResume

Answer (score 3):

Esto solo lo puedes saber en la misma aplicación, no desde otra aplicación.

Sobreescribe el método [`onResume()`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html) de tu `Activity`:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //La app esta en primer plano (foreground).
}
```

para saber si tu aplicación dejo de estar en "primer plano", o sea que se encuentre minimizada, lo puedes realizar mediante el método [`onPause()`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html):

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //La app esta en segundo plano (background).
}
```

Esto lo puedes ver en el diagrama del ciclo de vida de tu `Actvity`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]