# ¿Cómo saber si mi app está en segundo plano?

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo una app donde estoy reproduciendo un sonido de fondo. Pero si por alguna razón el usuario presiona el botón de "HOME", la app entra en segundo plano pero este sonido se sigue reproduciendo.

Me gustaría saber si hay algun modo de saber el estado en que se encuentra mi app para cuando ésta esté en segundo plano pausar la reproducción, y al volver, reanudar la reproducción.

Comment: Existen actualmente varias preguntas en el sitio donde se hace referencia a esto, dejo una respuesta y un enlace a otra donde puedes ver como determinar si tu aplicación esta en primer o segundo plano. @user27083 http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/42816/95

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe los metodos `onPause` y `onResume`. El primero se ejecutara cuando el usuario presione el boton HOME o baje la aplicacion, mientras que el segundo se ejecutara cuando el usuario vuelva a la aplicacion.

Estos métodos también se ejecutan cuando la aplicacion se inicia por primera vez y cuando la `Activity` se cierra. No se si existe la manera directa de solo el caso particular, pero podrias trabajar con variables `boolean` para identificar cuando entra por primera vez para asi no pausar el audio

Comment: sioesi y cuando se cierra la app del adm. de tareas, como puede seguir trabajando en segundo plano un procedimiento?

Comment: Un procedimiento sigue trabajando en segundo plano mientras no lo paras en _onPause()_ o _onStop()_. Solamente cuando la Activity termina (por llamada a _finish()_ o por decisión del sistemaapara liberar memoria) se termina tambien el procedimiento. Si quieres asegurarte que tareas sean procesados independiente del estado de la actividad, considera usar un _Service_.

Answer (score 3):

En base a esta pregunta:

**[Saber la aplicacion que esta en primer o segundo plano en Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22173/saber-la-aplicacion-que-esta-en-primer-plano-en-android/22176#22176)**

Te da idea de como saber si tu aplicación esta en primer o segundo plano, puedes saber si tu aplicación esta en "segundo plano" mediante el método [`onPause()`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html):

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //La app esta en segundo plano (background).
}
```

Esto lo puedes ver en el diagrama del ciclo de vida de tu `Actvity`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Revisa el [ciclo de vida](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) de la actividades. Siempre cuando una actividad deja ser de primer plano, se llama a *onPause()*, seguido por *onStop()* en el caso que la actividad ya no esta visible (por ser completamente tapado o sacado de la vista en el caso de tocar *HOME*). Luego volviendo a la vista se llaman a *onRestart()*, *onStart()* y *onResume()*.

En el enlace encuentras un diagrama útil para visualizar este flujo de trabajo en Android.

Answer (score 0):

> Indica si su aplicación se está ejecutando en FOREGROUND

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo#IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND_SERVICE

```
private boolean isExecute() {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info : processInfos) {

            if (BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID.equalsIgnoreCase(info.processName) && ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND == info.importance)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
```

}

Comment: las respuestas no se deben colocar en inglés, puesto que estas en la versión en español de SO; te invito a leer [answer]