# ¿Cuál es el evento para detectar cuando mi App se miniminiza?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-intent

Quiero detectar el evento que minimiza el `activity` de una `App` para ejecutar instrucciones, también tengo ingles nivel básico , pero no tiene este una información de las clases, como lo hace `netbeans` cuando programas java, este te da información de la API del método y clases.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> onCreate ()
>   Se llama cuando su actividad se está creado por primera vez.   Se
>   utiliza para inicializar la actividad, por ejemplo, crear la interfaz
>   de usuario.
>
> onStart ()
>   Este metodo se llama cuando la actividad se hace visible
>   para el usuario.
>
> onResume()
>   Esta se llama cuando el usuario comienza a interactuar
>   con la aplicación.
>
> onPause ()
>   Llamado cuando otra acividad se mete en primer plano. Siempre se
>   garantiza que su actividad se está convirtiendo en invisible o
>   parcialmente invisible. Se utiliza para liberar recursos o guardar los
>   datos de la aplicación. Pero una vez que se llama onPause, Android se
>   reserva el derecho de matar a su actividad en cualquier momento. Por
>   lo tanto usted no debería estar confiando en recibir eventos
>   adicionales.
>
> OnStop () 
>   Es llamado cuando la actividad ya no es visible.
>
> OnDestroy ()
>   Es llamado antes de que la actividad sea destruida por
>   el sistema.
>
> onRestart ()
>   Es llamado cuando la actividad se reinicia después de
>   detenerlo. Se llama sólo después OnStop

Más info:
http://www.codigojavalibre.com/2015/11/ciclo-de-vida-de-una-actividad-en-android-que-es-una-activity.html

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios métodos que entran en juego al volver atrás de Activity (onPause, onStop y onDestroy) o al "minimizar" la app (onPause y onStop), que forman parte del ciclo de vida de una Activity.[Más información acá.](http://www.androidcurso.com/index.php/tutoriales-android/37-unidad-6-multimedia-y-ciclo-de-vida/158-ciclo-de-vida-de-una-actividad)

Answer (score 1):

Cuando sales de una Activity sin cerrar la aplicación se llaman dos métodos onPause() y onStop() si quieres agregar algún comportamiento cuando esto sucede sólo escribe el método como lo haces con onCreate(). Por ejemplo:

```
protected void onPause() { //Todas tus instrucciones van dentro de este método o dentro de onStop()
    super.onPause();
    a = 5;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes saber si tu aplicación o Activity esta minimizada mediante el método [`onPause()`](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html):

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //La app esta minimizada!.
}
```

Revisando el ciclo de vida de tu `Actvity`, **cuando se minimiza (esta en "segundo plano") se llama el método `onPause()`**, cuando vuelve a estar visible se llama el método `onResume()`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Saber la aplicacion que esta en primer o segundo plano en Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22173/saber-la-aplicacion-que-esta-en-primer-plano-en-android)