# Ejecutar Activity mientras se muestra un Fragment

Tags: java, android, activity, fragment

mi pregunta es si, mientras se está visualizando un `Fragment`, sigue ejecutándose la `Activity` en segundo plano.

Sé que cuando pulsas el `onBackPressed()` se llama a la `Activity`, pero no sé si es caso especial o no.

Ahora mismo dispongo de una `Activity` que envía datos continuamente, y me gustaría ejecutar un `Fragment` mientras esto ocurre.

El `Fragment` para la visualización, y la `Activity` para los datos
¿Es posible?

Comment: Mario, agregué una respuesta, tu última pregunta: "El Fragment para la visualización, y la Activity para los datos ¿Es posible?" piensas obtener datos en la Activity y mostrarlos en la Interfaz de usuario? eso es lo que entiendo.

Answer (score 1):

**Sí que es posible.**

Una Activity podríamos entenderlo como una 'pantalla' y un fragment como una 'sección', puedes tener en primer plano varios fragment pero no varias activities y no puede haber un fragment sin su activity.

**Ejemplo:**

Puedes usar un FrameLayout donde quieras que se muestre el fragment dentro del layout de la activity, y después añadir el fragment a ese layout.

```
MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();

FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.content_frame, myFragment, MY_FRAGMENT_TAG).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Para remplazar el fragment si ha sido añadido anteriormente usa replace():

```
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, myFragment, MY_FRAGMENT_TAG).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Comment: No. La actividad se utiliza para conseguir otros datos que no guardan relación con el Fragment, pero es necesario ejecutar ambos a la vez.

Comment: Entonces ningún problema

Comment: He añadido como insertar o reemplazar el fragment en la activity

Answer (score 0):

> mi pregunta es si, mientras se está visualizando un Fragment, sigue
>   ejecutándose la Activity en segundo plano.

En realidad no tiene una ejecución en segundo plano ya que no llama [onPause()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/44004/95) la Activity en realidad actúa como un contenedor que contiene el `Fragment` e incluso puedes realizar transacciones entre `Fragments`.

> Sé que cuando pulsas el onBackPressed() se llama a la Activity, pero
>   no sé si es caso especial o no.

No es un caso especial, en realidad cuando tienes implementado el método `onBackPressed()` en la `Activity`, cuando ejecutas esta acción en realidad se llama en la `Activity`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     // realiza acción en Activity
     super.onBackPressed();  
}
```

Si tienes un Fragment en una Activity y deseas emular lo mismo desde el fragment se tendría que realizar mediante una [interface](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface):

Este es un [ejemplo](http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/10/01/handling-back-button-press-inside-fragments/):

```
// IMPLEMENTACION BASICA DE BACK EN FRAGMENT.

public abstract class BackHandledFragment extends Fragment {
    protected BackHandlerInterface backHandlerInterface;    
    public abstract String getTagText();
    public abstract boolean onBackPressed();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(!(getActivity()  instanceof BackHandlerInterface)) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Hosting activity must implement BackHandlerInterface");
    } else {
        backHandlerInterface = (BackHandlerInterface) getActivity();
    }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    // Mark this fragment as the selected Fragment.
    backHandlerInterface.setSelectedFragment(this);
    }

    public interface BackHandlerInterface {
    public void setSelectedFragment(BackHandledFragment backHandledFragment);
    }
}
```

> Ahora mismo dispongo de una Activity que envía datos continuamente, y
>   me gustaría ejecutar un Fragment mientras esto ocurre.

Puedes sin problema realizar la transacción para agregar un Fragment:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.contenedor, OtroFragment.newInstance());
transaction.commit();
```

> El Fragment para la visualización, y la Activity para los datos ¿Es
>   posible?

En realidad un **[Fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) representa un comportamiento o una parte de la interfaz de usuario en una Activity.** Puedes obtener los datos al inicio de la `Activity` y enviarlos al instanciar el `Fragment`, o incluso el mismo es importante mencionar que el `Fragment` podría realizar ambas tareas.

Comment: En realidad el fragment se encarga de ejecutar un código al que no tengo acceso (me lo provee otra compañía), por lo que no puedo modificar su comportamiento. Lo que me gustaría sería ejecutar la activity y el fragment (cuyo código no poseo). ¿Es posible?

Comment: marcaste la pregunta como respondida solo por un replace de fragmentos pero veo que es otra cosa la que necesitas,  Activity y el Fragment se puedn ejecutar ein ningun ptoblema, de hecho cuando estan la Activity y el Fragment en tu proyecto para Android Studio  sin duda podrías ver el código. si deseas especifica tu pregunta.